# Limited Dissolve - All Boundaries

Tags: mesh

What does the all boundaries option in limited dissolve actually do? The only information I was able to find was [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?368754-Limited-Dissolve-All-Boundaries-option-what-does-it-do) less than helpful thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh#Limited_Dissolve), *Limited Dissolve* without *All Boundaries* will:

> Limited Dissolve will have no affect on edges or vertices selected on the openings, but will limit the mesh appropriately on the edges/vertices away from the openings.

*Limited Dissolve* will affect only on edges / vertices which are located inside of closed areas (i.e. not closely to boundary loop).

*All Boundaries* checked will make tool to dissolve vertices located on the boundary loop if those vertices have no more than 2 edges connected to them.

Taking into consideration some examples, this will look as follows.

**Unfolded cube with edge loops in the corners**
[image: screenshot of comparing between options of limited dissolve]

- Loops were removed by both options;
- *All Boundaries* removed several faces of the mesh. Those were faces which haven't any further extruding out; their boundary vertices had only 2 edges connecting them - the ones which the actual face consisted of.

**UV sphere with several edges deleted**
[image: screenshot of comparing limited dissolve on sphere]

- Edge loops in the top (and bottom) part of the mesh were decreased in both cases, surrounding faces were converted into Ngons;
- *All Boundaries* option changed boundary loop (where mesh is opened); faces which had 1 vertex not connected to anything else were converted to tris, and that vertex dissolved.
- If sphere weren't opened, there wouldn't be any differences between *All Boundaries* turned on or off.

Generally *All Boundaries* may seem a bit strange because it dissolves geometry fallen under the threshold on the flat surfaces *and* around opened loops; thus if there isn't any supported geometry remained, the result won't be as expected:

[image: screenshot of unwanted result of limited dissolve]
<sub>Unexpected result of dissolving with *All Boundaries* turned on; the plane subdivisions were removed and hence was removed that part of plane because only 2 edges were touching vertices in the corners of the mesh after dissolving.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for super detailed response! I never realized that the dissolve applied before the all boundaries.